# How to get unique values in List

Tags: java, list, unique-values

I have 2 text files with data. I am reading these files with `BufferReader` and putting the data of one column per file in a `List<String>`.

I have duplicated data in each one, but I need to have unique data in the first `List` to confront with the duplicated data in the second `List`.

How can I get unique values from a `List`?

Comment: Don't add duplicate values if the List already `contains()` it?

Answer (score 24):

It can be done one one line by using an intermediate `Set`:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<>(list));
```

In java 8, use `distinct()` on a stream:

```
List<String> list = list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Alternatively, don't use a List at all; just use a Set (like HashSet) from the start for the collection you only want to hold unique values.

Comment: I think you mean: `list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @MoGa I was young, foolish and in love. Who can blame me for such folly? (thanks - code corrected)

Comment: lol your code actually pointed me to the right direction ;) cheers

Answer (score 11):

Convert the `ArrayList` to a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

```
List<String> listWithDuplicates; // Your list containing duplicates
Set<String> setWithUniqueValues = new HashSet<>(listWithDuplicates);
```

If for some reason, you want to convert the set back to a list afterwards, you can, but most likely there will be no need.

```
List<String> listWithUniqueValues = new ArrayList<>(setWithUniqueValues);
```

Comment: Thnks a lot for you answer.

Answer (score 3):

**In Java 8**:

```
     // List with duplicates
     List<String> listAll = Arrays.asList("A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "D");

     // filter the distinct 
     List<String> distinctList = listAll.stream()
                     .distinct()
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(distinctList);// prints out: [A, B, C, D]
```

this will also work with objects, but you will probably have to adapt your equals method.

Answer (score 0):

i just realize a solution may be it can be helpful for other persons.
first will be populated with duplicated values from BufferReader.

```
ArrayList<String> first = new ArrayList<String>();
```

To extract Unique values i just create a new ArrayList like down:

```
ArrayList<String> otherList = new ArrayList<>();

    for(String s : first) {
        if(!otherList.contains(s))
            otherList.add(s);
    }
```

A lot of post in internet are all speaking to assign my Arraylist to a List , Set , HashTable or TreeSet.
Can anyone explain the difference in theory and whitch one is the best tu use in practice ?
thnks for your time guys.

Comment: The Java API documentation provides elaborate documentation for each of the collection classes and interfaces. The [Wikipedia page on lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_(abstract_data_type)) also provides an overview and links to pages about other collection types.